# Multiple threads Create 5 threads to compute prime number

Tags: c++, multithreading

Please assist, I want to create 5 threads to compute the prime number. I have tried this way using this code below, but I have been told it's not correct.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 5
pthread_mutex_t mutexprime;
```

Comment: I didn't copy the all code:

Comment: That's not all. You should extend your question to an [mcve].

Comment: You tagged c++ so here you go: http://timmurphy.org/2010/05/04/pthreads-in-c-a-minimal-working-example/ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/  https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.thread-management If you code in c++ i suggest the second. 3 different approaches

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example how to make as much threads as you want. Hope it helps.

```
    int main() {
    int num_threads;

    cout << endl << "Enter number of threads: ";
    cin >> num_threads;


    vector<thread> t;

    for (int i = 0;i <= num_threads;i++) {

    t.push_back(thread(/*fucntion*/, ref(/*add here variable1*/), ref(/*here variable 2*/))); 
        }


        for (auto &tt : t) { tt.join(); //Join the threads when finish
        t.clear();//clean vector.
        system("cls");
    }


    return 0;
   }
```

Do not forget to block your variables with `mutex`